# Where do undeclared variables go in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

Example:

```
st> [ fnord := 7 ] value
```

I was always under the impression that they went into the SystemDictionary at `Smalltalk`, but that's not true:

```
st> [ fnord := 7 ] value
st> Smalltalk at: #fnord
Object: SystemDictionary new: 512 "<0x2acfca382030>" error: Invalid argument #fnord: key not found
```

However, at least on GNU Smalltalk, the values seem to be persisted *somewhere* --- accessing `fnord` returns the right value:

```
st> [ fnord := 7 ] value
st> fnord
7
```

**Update:** I figured out how to disassemble blocks! It's really hard.

```
st> [ fnord := 7 ] block inspect
An instance of CompiledBlock
  header: 32768
    clean-ness flags: 0
    number of arguments: 0
    number of temporaries: 0
    number of literals: 4
    needed stack slots: 8
  method: UndefinedObject>>executeStatements
  literals: [
    [1] {fnord}
    [2] a BlockClosure
    [3] #block
    [4] #inspect
  ]
  byte codes: [
    [1] source code line number 1
    [3] push 7
    [5] store into Global Variable {fnord}
    [7] pop stack top
    push Global Variable {fnord}
    [9] return stack top
  ]
[] in UndefinedObject>>executeStatements
```

So it definitely *thinks* it's writing to a global variable.

Comment: I don't know Gnu Smalltalk specifically (in fact, I can't really imagine doing Smalltalk from a command line), but shouldn't temporary variables typically get the smallest possible scope? The SystemDictionary (i.e. global scope) wouldn't be very good, as it would get polluted with lots of throwaway entries. In other flavours of Smalltalk, executing code not "tied" to a method somewhere (e.g. from selecting text and executing it) would get assigned a temporary context (you might see `UndefinedObject>>DoIt` in Pharo, for instance).

Comment: But don't local variables require declaration with `| fnord |`? In fact, I managed to disassemble the block, and it's definitely trying to write to a global --- whatever that is...

Comment: Hrm. I tried this in Amber, and my block failed to compile, claiming that `fnord` was undeclared. Maybe this is a GSTism. Unfortunately I don't have access to Squeak or Pharo so can't try it there.

Comment: @DavidGiven Squeak runs in your web browser: http://try.squeak.org/

Answer (score 2):

Undeclared variable bindings go into a global dictionary named `Undeclared`. That binding (a `key->value` pair) gets moved to `Smalltalk` once you properly declare it. This is how forward-references are resolved when loading code, for example. That is, when a variable is used before the code declaring it is loaded.

Comment: Is this a standard Smalltalk thing, or specific to one particular version? I ask because I can't find `Undeclared` in my (poorly searchable) Blue Book.

Comment: Yes it's standard Smalltalk-80.